# Getting information from HTML page via VBA

Tags: html, vba

From VBA, I am trying to access to the "username" cell from a web page so that I could type in the appropriate username.

The problem is that in the HTML code from the page we have more than one element with the same name which is "LOGON_USERID" and I can't figure out how to access to the right one.

As you can see on the image "part of the HTML code", the line I'm trying to access to is the highlighted one, but there are also 2 other elements which have the same name above it.

[part of the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XySve.png)

I tried lots of different ways (using different methods or variable types etc), but since I'm not familiar with HTML I can't manage to get what I want.

```
Sub  Pum()    

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
'Dim IEDoc As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim name As Object
Dim nameList As HTMLInputElement
Dim WRONGS As DispHTMLElementCollection
Dim Elems As HTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Integer

ie.navigate "thewebsiteinquestion"


ie.Visible = False


WaitIE ie


Set IEDoc = ie.document
'MsgBox IEDoc.DocumentElement.
'Elems = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
 MsgBox TypeName(IEDoc.getElementById("LOGON_USERID").all)
Set Elems = IEDoc.getElementById("LOGON_USERID")
 'For i = 0 To 5
 MsgBox Elems.Length
'Next i
 For Each name In Elems.Children
 MsgBox name.nodeName
 MsgBox name.Attributes
 MsgBox name.all

Next


'If ((NameStr Isnot Nothing And (NameStr.Length <> 0)) Then
'If NameStr = "LOGON_USERID" Then
'If TypeName(IEDoc.all("LOGON_USERID")) = "HTMLInputElement" Then


    'MsgBox TypeName(IEDoc.all("LOGON_USERID"))
    'Set names = IEDoc.all.Item("text")
    'TypeName (InputUsernameTextzone)
    'Dim Question As IHTMLElement
    'Question = InputUsernameTextzone.parentElement
   'MsgBox TypeName(InputUsernameTextzone.parentElement.getAttribute("name"))
  'InputUsernameTextzone.parentElement

    'CELLULE.value = "qtc2464"



  WaitIE ie


  Set ie = Nothing
  Set IEDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried two other similar codes using different methods but I still have no results. Hopefully you can help me.

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Automating in this fashion can be a tricky business.  Especially if you don't own the website.  Each time the website is updated your code will be at risk of failing.  Does the website publish an API you could use instead?

Comment: @destination-data : hey, basically this is the webpage from the company I work in and my idea was to access to the datas directly with the macro so that the updates could be done automatically. The only thing we have to provide on this page is the username and our password. I'm not familiar with the term APi, but after searching its meaning I guess there's no such things that I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other two input elements are of different type (they are *hidden*) so you could use `querySelector` with attribute `type=text` to find your desired element.

```
Dim userid As HTMLInputElement
Set userid = IEDoc.querySelector("input[name='LOGON_USERID'][type='text']")

If Not userid Is Nothing Then
    ' Continue with user id element
Else
    MsgBox "LOGON_USERID not found on the page"
End If
```

Comment: EDIT : It works !! Thank you so much. I was literally on this for a good 8 h I swear !!

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie at this but if this could help anyone, here's the simplified version of the macro I made :

```
Sub Access_Puma()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim userid As HTMLInputElement
Dim userpwd As HTMLInputElement
          ie.navigate "thewebsitetoaccess"

ie.Visible = True


WaitIE ie

  Set IEDoc = ie.document

Set userid = IEDoc.querySelector("input[name='LOGON_USERID'][type='text']")
If Not userid Is Nothing Then
userid.value = "myusername"
Else
MsgBox "LOGON_USERID not found on the page"
End If

Set userpwd = IEDoc.querySelector("input[name='LOGON_PASSWD'][type='password']")
If Not userpwd Is Nothing Then
userpwd.value = "mypassword"
Else
MsgBox "LOGON_PASSWD not found on the page"
End If
End Sub
```